# Running the output of script, and checking for consistency

Tags: linux, diff, tcsh

Given a file that was output by `script`, is there a way to run all of those commands in order, and then check to see if the output matches what was in the script file?

I assume that `diff` can be used for the last part, but I have no idea on how to do the first. Any ideas?

Using a tcsh shell on linux (Debian, but I doubt it matters).

Comment: The answer is going to be yes regardless, but some environmental information would help you get a better answer. Window? Unix? What shell?

Comment: @EBGreen, see edit

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: From the manual:

> Script places everything in the log file, including linefeeds and backspaces.  This is not what the naive user expects.

This means it might be possible to do in the simplest cases, by looking for occurrences of `$PS1` in the output and running the string after it, but it could soon become impossible:

- You can't see the difference between a literal character and an escape character like `^C`.
- Any background jobs can insert text at any time, messing up the output. `while true; do sleep $RANDOM; echo garbage; done &`
- If it records standard error, there's the whole asynchronous output issue.

If it's at all an option, I'd rather use /var/log/cmdlog, and see if all of the text produced by the commands recorded there occur anywhere within the `script` file.

Comment: I do not want to redo all the work I have already done, hence the first part of the question. How can I get the commands out of the script file?

Comment: Copy and paste. It should run just as if you'd run the original script, only in the different context.

Comment: No, as every keypress (even up arrow) is recorded, and that messes up the terminal. In addition, it would run the output of the commands, which is also something I don't want

Comment: If it's an interactive application, you're probably better off using `expect`. But this does *not* run the *output* of the commands - `(command)` is different from `$(command)`.

Comment: When I say `script` I mean the command `script` not some script I wrote. Your answer does not seem to be aware of this

Comment: Ah, discovering new commands every day. I assumed by `script` you meant some random script file you'd written.

Comment: Cmdlog is not useful (has been wiped since, and replaced with new commands etc). Any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so one of the semantics of `diff` is that it outputs text if the files differ, and outputs nothing if they are the same.

Given files `foo` and `bar`, here's what you can do:

```
# Run your script
if [ "$(diff foo bar)" = "" ]; then
    echo "They are the same"
else
    echo "They are different"
fi
```

(You're first part isn't exactly clear - do you have a sample output `out.template` and `script > out.log` and want to make sure that `out.template` and `out.log` are the same? Or something else?)

Comment: It is not a script in the sense that it is some script that can run. It is a script in the sense that it is the output of the script command. How can I run it?

Comment: @soandos Not easily - it dumps everything from VT100 color escapes to output from `ncurses` programs. (The manpage states that `this is not what the naive user expects`).